# Splash screen blurry LibGdx android 2.3

Tags: android, libgdx, splash-screen

Testing my application written in libgdx on an old version Android (GingerBread) I noticed that the splash screen is extra blurry showing all types of colors. Everything else is working fine except this.

```
public class Monkeyman extends ApplicationAdapter {

private SpriteBatch batch;
private GameStateManager gsm;
private ActionResolver actionResolver;


Monkeyman(ActionResolver actionResolver) {
    this.actionResolver = actionResolver;
}


@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    gsm = new GameStateManager();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    gsm.push(new SplashState(gsm, actionResolver));


}

@Override
public void render() {

    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gsm.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    gsm.render(batch);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
}
}
```

I draw it in render method like this:

```
sb.draw(background, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

It's working fine on Marshmallow as well. Is it because of the versoin of GL?